# Spring Data JpaRepository sets null for entities not referenced in query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have JpaRepository that return Run objects, where each Run objects has a `@ManyToOne` relation to a Device. All relations are set in the correct form.

But, When I run a request like this:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Run a WHERE a.date >= :startDate AND a.date <= :endDate AND (a.device.treeName IN (:devices))")
```

Run object has a correct reference to Device.

But for this request:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Run a WHERE a.date >= :startDate AND a.date <= :endDate")
```

the Device is always null.

when I run the first request and then the second one on the same transaction it does work !

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in the first case, device object is also loaded since you are checking `a.device.treeName IN (:devices)` in the where clause.

In the second case, since I guess you have set lazy loading to true, its not loaded,so you get device as NULL.

Try below :

```
@Query("  FROM Run a WHERE a.date >= :startDate AND a.date <= :endDate")
```

Try below as well:

```
@Query(" select a FROM Run a JOIN FETCH a.device WHERE a.date >= :startDate AND a.date <= :endDate")
```

Comment: I didn't mention `FetchType` - isn't `EAGER` the default ?

Comment: FetchType is lazy by default.

Comment: Changed to `EAGER`, modified the `@Query`. still not working.

Comment: Try this one as well : @Query("  FROM Run a JOIN FETCH a.device WHERE a.date >= :startDate AND a.date <= :endDate")

Comment: `QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list `

Comment: @Query(" select a FROM Run a JOIN FETCH a.device WHERE a.date >= :startDate AND a.date <= :endDate")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111989/discussion-between-nati-and-shankarsh15).